What happens if I have multiple IP addresses in a single weighted routing record in route 53?
Basically the title.
I am in the process of migrating from simple routing to weighted routing and wanted to test using a few servers.
Currently, we have a single A record which is simple routing, it consists of all the server IPs.
I am trying to take out some servers and add some weighted routing entries for the same.
If I have 3 records,
Record A - weighted, 2 IPs, weight 50
Record B - weighted, 1 IP,    weight 50
Will each of the IPs in record A get equal traffic, I.e 25%?
I was not able to replicate the above.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Scenario:
Created a single weighted routing record in route 53 with multiple IPs in a single record.
Expectations: each IP should get equal traffic.
Observations: the first IP of the record gets the most traffic.
